# How to use realm with RxJava2

Tags: android, kotlin, realm, observable, rx-java2

I am using RxJava 2 and Realm in my project and I was fetching data from RealmResults using Observable. Here is my code .

```
fun getAllAsync(){
    realm?.where(RealmSuggestedFriends::class.java)
            ?.findAllAsync()
            ?.asFlowable()
            ?.filter { t -> t.isLoaded }
            ?.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            ?.subscribe({
        t: RealmResults<RealmSuggestedFriends>? ->for (firstResults in t!!){
        val requestPojo = RequestPojo()
        requestPojo.email = firstResults.friendEmail
        requestPojo.image = firstResults.friendImage
        requestPojo.name = firstResults.friendName
        requestPojo.status = firstResults.friendStatus
        requestPojo.thumb_image = firstResults.friendThumbImage
        requestPojo.uid = firstResults.friendUid
        userAdapter?.addData(requestPojo)
    }
    },{
        t: Throwable? ->
      },
      {},
      {})
    }
```

I tried above code but i ain't getting any data. After this, I tried to fetch data by this way

```
Observable.create<RealmSuggestedFriends> { emitter ->
        val results = realm?.where(RealmSuggestedFriends::class.java)
                ?.findAllAsync()
        for (suggestedFriends in results!!){
            emitter.onNext(suggestedFriends)
        }
        emitter.onComplete()
    }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .flatMap { firstResults ->
                val requestPojo = RequestPojo()
                requestPojo.email = firstResults.friendEmail
                requestPojo.image = firstResults.friendImage
                requestPojo.name = firstResults.friendName
                requestPojo.status = firstResults.friendStatus
                requestPojo.thumb_image = firstResults.friendThumbImage
                requestPojo.uid = firstResults.friendUid
                Observable.just(requestPojo).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            }
            .subscribe({
                t: RequestPojo? ->  userAdapter?.addData(t!!)
            },{
                t: Throwable? ->  
            },{

            },{
                t: Disposable? ->  compositeDisposable?.add(d!!)
            })
```

Using this code also , I ain't getting any data and also i get a toast of saying `Realm accessed from incorrect thread` . Anybody help me to make it work. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Single.create<List<RealmSuggestedFriends>> { emitter ->
    Realm.getDefaultInstance().use { realm ->
        val results = realm.where(RealmSuggestedFriends::class.java).findAll()
        emitter.onSuccess(realm.copyFromRealm(results))
    }
}.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
 .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
 .map { results ->
     for(firstResults in results) {
        val requestPojo = RequestPojo()
        requestPojo.email = firstResults.friendEmail
        requestPojo.image = firstResults.friendImage
        requestPojo.name = firstResults.friendName
        requestPojo.status = firstResults.friendStatus
        requestPojo.thumb_image = firstResults.friendThumbImage
        requestPojo.uid = firstResults.friendUid
     }
 }.subscribe({    
     list: List<RequestPojo> ->  userAdapter.updateData(list)
 },{
     t: Throwable? ->  
 },{
 })
```

Assuming you don't want to get notifications when the Realm changes, anyways.

Otherwise, use Observable, kinda like [this one](https://github.com/Zhuinden/simple-stack/blob/f1dc9ffa24d2e44400e1ea22b9d16199de24ef1a/simple-stack-example-mvp-fragments/src/main/java/com/zhuinden/simplestackdemoexamplefragments/data/repository/TaskRepository.java#L65):

```
private Observable<List<Task>> createResults(QuerySelector<DbTask> querySelector) {
    return Observable.create((ObservableOnSubscribe<List<Task>>) emitter -> {
        Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        final RealmResults<DbTask> dbTasks = querySelector.createQuery(realm);
        final RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<DbTask>> realmChangeListener = element -> {
            if(element.isLoaded() && !emitter.isDisposed()) {
                List<Task> tasks = mapFrom(element);
                if(!emitter.isDisposed()) {
                    emitter.onNext(tasks);
                }
            }
        };
        emitter.setDisposable(Disposables.fromAction(() -> {
            if(dbTasks.isValid()) {
                dbTasks.removeChangeListener(realmChangeListener);
            }
            realm.close();
        }));
        dbTasks.addChangeListener(realmChangeListener);
    }).subscribeOn(looperScheduler.getScheduler()).unsubscribeOn(looperScheduler.getScheduler());
}
```

To get the second one to work, you can even try out [my library that helps with this](https://github.com/Zhuinden/realm-monarchy/blob/c65b2ad3a9bfcf1d356ab7be66d4ddce9f3781e9/monarchy-example/src/main/java/com/zhuinden/monarchyexample/features/mapped_rx/MappedRxFragment.java#L67-L69).

```
Flowable<List<Dog>> dogs;

@Inject
Monarchy monarchy;

private List<Dog> currentDogs = Collections.emptyList();

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    LiveData<List<Dog>> dogs = monarchy.findAllMappedWithChanges(realm -> realm.where(RealmDog.class),
                                                           from -> Dog.create(from.getName()));
    this.dogs = Flowable.fromPublisher(LiveDataReactiveStreams.toPublisher(getActivity(), dogs));
```

Comment: I like the first one. I'll try it. But i wanna ask about copyToRealm. why did you used here and if meanwhile data changes in Realm then my RealmResults automatically update or I'll have to use realm change listener for that thing.Thanks Again..

Comment: Actually, you should not like the first one :D but you can actually also try out my library that can help with [Rx integration using LiveData's Rx integration](https://github.com/Zhuinden/realm-monarchy/blob/c65b2ad3a9bfcf1d356ab7be66d4ddce9f3781e9/monarchy-example/src/main/java/com/zhuinden/monarchyexample/features/mapped_rx/MappedRxFragment.java#L67-L69), it should do exactly what you want.

Comment: why i should not use the first one ?. Is it wrong to do that way ?

Comment: Because you don't subscribe for changes :D Technically it reads data from background thread and boom it's one-off. I prefer to subscribe, but if you want to map out to another object type (which you do!) then you should do that on a background thread, right? So you should look at the edit I added regarding my library, see if that works for you. There's a sample for it and everything :) So it should!

Comment: so you mean if any data changes then it won't reflect on the copied list. right ?

Comment: Yeah, in the case of the Single, it wouldn't.

Comment: okay , thanks .. I'll read about your library. I guess it will work perfectly in that scenario.